# numpy rounds floats in an array to ints, but I don't want that

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have the following code

```
import numpy as np

arr=np.array([[3,2,1],[4,3,1],[3,1,0]])
x=np.array([16,21.7,12.1])

for i in range(len(arr)):
    temp=np.copy(arr)
    temp[:,i]=x
```

when I execute this instead of making `temp=[[3,2,16],[4,3,21.7],[3,1,12.1]]` it makes `[[3,2,16],[4,3,21],[3,1,12]]`. it rounds but I don't want that. I used `.astype()`, `float()` etc. but didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `dtype=float` to `arr`

```
arr = np.array([[3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 1], [3, 1, 0]], dtype=float)
...
print(temp)

# [[ 3.   2.  16. ]
#  [ 4.   3.  21.7]
#  [ 3.   1.  12.1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the array as a float type

```
arr=np.array([[3,2,1],[4,3,1],[3,1,0]]).astype(np.float32)
```

or convert it as you copy it

```
    temp=np.copy(arr).astype(np.float32)
```